# Showing a sheet on a full screen cover doesn't make the full screen view scale

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a full screen cover view (orange background), it has sheets that it wants to display over the top (green background), these sheets show up fine but the full screen view behind (orange) doesn't scale down like a sheet would normally cause it to do.

```
VStack {
  VStack {
    Spacer()
    buttons
    Text("Hello, World!")
      .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .center)
    Spacer()
  }
  .background(.gray)
  .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $fullScreen) {
    VStack {
      Spacer()
      buttons
      Text("FullScreen")
        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .center)
      Spacer()
    }
    .background(.orange)
    .sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
      VStack {
        Spacer()
        buttons
        Text("Sheet")
          .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .center)
        Spacer()
      }
      .background(.green)
      .presentationDetents([.large])
    }    
  }
}
```

Is there a way to trigger the full screen view behind to scale down?

| What I want it to look like | What it looks like |
| --- | --- |
| [image: What I want it to look like] | [image: What it looks like] |

Comment: No, the `fullScreenCover` literally covers the full screen, if you want a `sheet` look use a `sheet`

Comment: totally, i want the full screen cover to cover the screen but I want it to also scale down when i put a sheet over the full screen cover